# How to get Y coordinate for every element in FlatList in React Native (Expo)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm building UI for my app and I'd like to know the y coordinate of the element that the user clicks on in my FlatList. What causes variables I create in `onLayout` not to appear in `onPress`, and how can I fix it?

```
<FlatList
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  data={data}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onLayout={(event) => {
        var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
      }} 
      onPress={()=>{console.log(y)}}> //Can't find variable: y
      <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)}/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onLayout` is only called on the initial render and if the element changes. The element most likely isn't changing while you're scrolling, so its position on screen isn't measured again.

The best way I know to handle this is to store the ref of the list item, and run its `measure` method when it's touched. You can read about `measure` here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback

You'd have to make a new component instead of writing it inline in the FlatList render method, something like:

```
const ListButton = ({ text, onPress }) => {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const onPressWithMeasure = () => {
    buttonRef.current?.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      console.log(x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
      onPress();
    });
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressWithMeasure} ref={buttonRef}>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

And then in your FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ListButton text={item.text} onPress={() => {}} />
  )}
/>
```

In the comments a method was requested to set the layout of the individual button based on its width.  This can be accomplished using local state and onLayout:

```js
const ListButton = ({ text, onPress }) => {
  const [totalWidth, setTotalWidth] = useState(0); // new
  ...

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPressWithMeasure}
      ref={buttonRef}
      onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => setTotalWidth(nativeEvent.layout.width)} // new
      style={{ marginLeft: totalWidth }} // new
    >
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! One more question similar to this, how would I use ```pageY``` in ```<Text>``` style? Let's say I want all elements to have ```marginLeft: pageY```, btw you need to add ```)}``` before return in your code

Comment: Sure! Fixed the syntax error, thanks. If you want to apply the margin to all elements - not just the one that was touched - you need to pass a setter down from the parent. Add a state value for the margin to the parent, and pass the callback that sets that state to each ListButton. Then you can set the margin from within the callback you pass to `measure`. You could either apply the margin to the parent styles or pass it down to each child. Let me know if you would like a code example.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could provide me with a code example. Because I don't think I explained it well, let me explain what I want more clearly. Each element in FlatList should have margin left equal to its width, and I don't want to set it in ```onPress```, I want it set at the start of my app (I used pageY since it was easier for me to explain my problem). For example, if the width of the text is 20, I want the left margin to be 20. The length of the text would be different for every element, so each element would have a different margin left.

Comment: For that you could use onLayout.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking, but I don't know how to do it. If I add this to my code ```<Text style={{marginLeft:width}}>{item.text}</Text>``` the error occurs, Can't find variable: width. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not in scope there, you can assign the width to state in onLayout.  I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works, but there is a problem I don't know how to explain [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@perasa3a/hi). See how it flickers? I think it's because it's constantly setting state and refreshing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, it was because the layout was updating, which set the totalWidth, which changed the layout, so it created a cycle.  Fixed [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@256hz/hi) although this comment section probably could have been a separate question.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with everything I asked, you saved me. I agree that this could be separate question.